# DisplayMode / DiplayMode Providers Issue Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying out MVC 4 lately. Started with the developer preview, and now the beta.

Everything was working quite well, but I wanted make use of the built in minification & compression features. But it seemed like it wasn't present in the developer previews as no matter what i attempted the code wouldn't compile/provide a clean run, if i added anything bundling related. I then did some research and saw MVC 4 beta.

I uninstalled mvc 4 and re-installed it using the beta installer. Created a new project and it ran fine using the bundling. But no matter what I did, (Including copying the dll's from the new solution, to my old one.) I cant get the bundling to work in my existing solution

In the global.asax.cs file

[1]

***BundleTable***.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();

Bundle Table wont even register. (gets red underline)

[2]

I tried something else just to verify that the new dll are being used.

previously to check for a display mode the following would be used

```
[a]
    DisplayModes.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
    {
      ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
                         ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    });
```

but it's since been updated to

```
[b]
    DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
    ...
```

The code will compile if I use [a], and not [b], but it wont give me a clean run using [a], as it errors out during runtime

*Could not load type 'System.Web.WebPages.DisplayModes' from assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.*

Could it be that my old solution is still referencing the old dlls somehow, even if i copied the new ones over, removed the references and manually pointed them to the new ones?

---

The reference entries as requested by @Brad Christie

```
<Reference Include="EntityFramework">
  <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.4.1.10331.0\lib\net40\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Json, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Json.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Json.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.Formatting.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebPages.Core.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebApi.Core.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.Common, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\System.Web.Http.Common.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.Common.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebApi.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetMvc.4.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Optimization.1.0.0-beta\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetRazor.Core.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebPages.Core.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebPages.Core.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AspNetWebPages.Core.2.0.20126.16343\lib\net40\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer i was hoping for, but it got the job done. I ended up creating a new solution, and moving my code to it. Seemed to do the trick. Not sure why the previous solution wasn't updating properly though :/

Try going to your solution explorer, and right clicking on the root solution and checking the properties. Under common properties -> Project dependencies, make sure that the relevant projects are checked.

Comment: I still have this same issue. You never found out the problem? Can you maybe dump the project's `<Reference>` entries?

Answer (score 2):

I added this to my class and got it working:

```
using System.Web.WebPages;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and it took 1 day to resolve this.
I checked everything (assembly ref/replacing assembly).

finally uninstall the **asp .net web pages** and re-installed it and that works.

hope this will help