# can't find DisplayModeProvider Class in System.Web.WebPages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, upgrade

After upgrading from MVC3 to MVC4 following this link [Upgrading an ASP.NET MVC 3 Project to ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) that just needs to do some changes in config files, everything is working as a web application but when I wanted to test it for mobile application , I wanted to add in my Global.asax.cs file something like that :

```
DisplayModes.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
  ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
                     ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

but it said that it cannot find DisplayModeProvider Class in System.Web.WebPages !
Any help please

Comment: I +1'd @Kyle's answer as that is the code you'd need. However, see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886356/displaymode-diplaymode-providers-issue-asp-net-mvc-4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
{
  ContextCondition = (context => context.Request.UserAgent.IndexOf
                     ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
});
```

Comment: it doesn't recognized DisplayModeProvider either I tried to make the dll call using System.Web.WebPages more specific but I couldn"t find DisplayModeProvider and all I can find were ApplicationParts ; Html; Resources; Scope ! does that mean that the System.Web.WebPages dll is not updated and still in its version  1.0.0.0 ??

Comment: @Glolita may be, expand your references folder find system.web.webpages and click properties. If it doesn't say 2.0.0.0 then that may be your issue.